# Chromium with SeleneseTestCase

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, chromium

I want to run Selenium test case with Chromium under Debian 6, which doesn't have any User Interface. For this I'm using 'xsimulator'. I set up my test:

`public void setUp() throws Exception{
         setName("test");
         super.setUp("http://www.wikipedia.org/", "*googlechrome chromium-
         browser);
         }`

It starts Chromium instance without any problem, but, since it's the first run of Chromium, it asks me make the default browser. Without UI (I'm on xsimulator) I can't click and make any of the choices. Actually, Chromium allows to start it without asking default browser check (argument '--no-default-browser-check'), but this only works in terminal. When I set up test like this:

`super.setUp("http://www.wikipedia.org/", "*googlechrome usr/bin/chromium-browser --no-default-browser-check");`

It throws null pointer exception:

`java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.browserlaunchers.GoogleChromeLauncher.createCommandArray(GoogleChromeLauncher.java:168)`

Another workaround could be to make the chrome default by running it on terminal using '--make-default-browser' argument, but unfortunately this leads to 'xdg' fault:

`xdg-settings: unknown desktop environment
Segmentation fault`

My question is: how to set up chromium browser in selenium test case with browser specific arguments like mentioned above or avoid default browser check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem was to force Chromium start without any first run specific actions, either via Selenium or manually.
I couldn't find the way to set up chromium browser in selenium test case with browser specific arguments, but I found a workaround to force Chromium to not ask me to `"make Chromium the default browser"`.

For this:

1. Go to Chromium profile dir (usually - `/"current user"/.config/chromium/`)
2. Switch to `"Default"` dir
3. Edit file `"Preferences"` by adding in `"browser"` section
   `"check_default_browser": false,`
4. Go to `/"current user"/.config/chromium` and create empty file called `"First Run"`

This will force the Chromium start normally.